# Minimizing the MSE of a cosine Fourier Series

Tags: physics

When approximating an even function with period $2\pi$ by a Fourier-cosine-Series with $m$ terms, it has the error
$$E_m=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[f(x)-\frac{a_0}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \cos(nx)\right]^2 dx$$

Now I have to find the $a_n$'s which minimize this error.
I got to the point where:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx) dx$$
But I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: If $f$ is odd and cosine is even, then the product is odd. So the integral is $0$.

Comment: thanks, sorry I made a few mistakes in the problem description, function is meant to be even

Comment: You got it right. The $a_n$ coefficients that minimize the sum are the Fourier coefficients of the expansion.

Comment: ok, thanks again, but do you know how to minimze?

Comment: You told that you got to the formula for $a_n$. How did you get there, if not by minimizing?

Answer (score 1):

You want to choose $a_n$ to mimimize
$$E_m=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[f(x)-\frac{a_0}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \cos(nx)\right]^2 dx$$
Then $$\frac{dE_m}{da_k}=0,\forall k\in \overline{0,m}$$
You can switch the order of the derivative and the integral. For $k=0$ you get $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{-1}22 \left[f(x)-\frac{a_0}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \cos(nx)\right] dx=0$$
Notice that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(nx)dx=0$$
With that $$\frac{a_0}2\int_{-\pi}^\pi dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx$$or$$a_0=\frac 1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx$$
For all other terms you have $$-2\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(kx)\left[f(x)-\frac{a_0}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \cos(nx)\right] dx=0$$
We know that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(kx)dx=0$$
For $n\ne k$
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(kx)\cos(nx)dx=\frac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi[\cos(k-n)x+\cos(k+n)x ]dx=0$$
and for $n=k$
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2(kx)dx=\frac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi[1+\cos(2kx)]dx=\pi$$
With these, you get $$a_k\pi=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx$$

Comment: Okay, thank you Andrei, this helped a lot.